# Sitecore Azure Error : Instance validation error: '2014-06.2.4' is not a valid value for SchemaVersion

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore-azure

When I click on Sitecore Azure module from my Sitecore desktop I'm getting bellow given error. I've Sitecore SDK 2.9 installed

Instance validation error: '2014-06.2.4' is not a valid value for SchemaVersion.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: '2014-06.2.4' is not a valid value for SchemaVersion.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: '2014-06.2.4' is not a valid value for SchemaVersion.]
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderServiceDefinition.Read68_SchemaVersion(String s) +123
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderServiceDefinition.Read71_ServiceDefinition(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +585
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderServiceDefinition.Read72_ServiceDefinition() +116

[InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 147).]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +857
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader) +159
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureDeployments.Deployment.LoadData() +568
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureDeployments.AzureDeployment.LoadData() +17
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureEntity..ctor(AzureEntity parentNode, Item storeItem) +196
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureDeployments.ContentDeliveryDeployment..ctor(WebRole parentNode, DeploymentItem item) +30
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.EntitiesFactory.Create(Item item, AzureEntity parent) +2431
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureEntity..ctor(AzureEntity parentNode, Item storeItem) +334
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.EntitiesFactory.Create(Item item, AzureEntity parent) +1581
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureEntity..ctor(AzureEntity parentNode, Item storeItem) +334
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.EntitiesFactory.Create(Item item, AzureEntity parent) +1464
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureEntity..ctor(AzureEntity parentNode, Item storeItem) +334
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.EntitiesFactory.Create(Item item, AzureEntity parent) +1881
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureEntity..ctor(AzureEntity parentNode, Item storeItem) +334
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.Environments.Environment..ctor(AzureEntity parentNode, EnvironmentDefinition environmentDefinition, EnvironmentItem item) +41
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.EntitiesFactory.Create(Item item, AzureEntity parent) +2292
   Sitecore.Azure.Deployments.AzureEntity..ctor(AzureEntity parentNode, Item storeItem) +334
   Sitecore.Azure.Configuration.Settings.get_EnvironmentsRoot() +150
   Sitecore.Azure.Managers.AzureManagers.TrafficProfilesManager.GetGlobalDomainURIs() +76
   Sitecore.Azure.UI.Shell.Applications.Azure.AzureManagerForm.TrafficManagerInitialising(String environmnentType, DeploymentSlot slot, String& startupScript) +124
   Sitecore.Azure.UI.Shell.Applications.Azure.AzureManagerForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +159

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +594
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

Comment: Now the error changed to The type or namespace name 'Shell' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.Azure.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by searching in sitecore for 2014-06.2.4 and replacing this value with 2015-04.2.6